# how to group values belonging to same group in same column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table that contains the purchases of customers on a supermarket, the maximum number of products purchased is 11 and the minimum is 1.

Each row represents a unique customer:

```
data.head(9)
```

[image]

I want to group the purchased products according to their group (type) in order to analyze each group independently.
for example, I want to group the Fruits products in column 1, the vegetable products in column 2 ...etc.

for example; the second customer doesn't buy vegetables so in the output, the vegetable cell is empty. But he bought Lip balm (it is a cosmetic), so in the output, it will be placed in the cosmetics column.

This table is the output of the first table, I use colors to differentiate between groups of products (types of product). I want output like that:

```
output.head(9)
```

[image]

I have another table that contains the groups and their all possible values:

```
groups.head()
```

[image]

NOTE: each customer has purchased only one product from the same group.

How can do that in python dataframe?

Comment: In the first table, what rows or columns does correspond to the products names ? For example, I can't see dairy_product_1 or cosmetic_product_2 nowhere in the first table.

Comment: The structure of your data isn't clear. Could you please add to your question a sample data you are working with? Also it would be great to see what have you tried.

Comment: Also, please show desired output. Unclear what you mean by *group values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''
item1,item2,item3
lemon,potato,
potato,yogurt,coconut
coconut,broccoli,
curd,,
'''

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

groups = '''
fruits,vegetables,dairy
lemon,potato,yogurt
coconut,broccoli,curd
,corn,
'''

groups = pd.read_csv(StringIO(groups))
groups = (
    groups
    .melt(var_name='group',value_name='product')
    .dropna()
    .set_index('product')
    .squeeze()
)

output = data.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series({groups[p]: p for p in row.dropna()}), 
    axis=1
)
```

[image]